# TYPO3 Bootstrap Package: Picture smaller / adding picture layout

Tags: typo3

I'm using the TYPO3 bootstrap package. The picture in a content element is always 100%. I would like to get the picture smaller (fixed at 20px). First I thought of using TSConfig to adjust the size. But this doesn't work because I have images I would like to still have 100%. So I think the best way is creating an additional content element layout. How can I add a new dropdown entry?

[image: add additional layout]

Answer (score 0):

You can add items to every dropdown list with TSConfig. In your case you want to extend table `tt_content` and field `layout`.

```
TCEFORM.tt_content.layout.addItems.1525215969 = Your layout name
```

The number can be any number you want. It just has to be unique.

See the official [documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tsconfig/10.4/en-us/PageTsconfig/TceForm.html#additems) for details.

Comment: Looks nice. And how I can add a template or css file according to "Your layout name"?
Do you know with template file / css is associated with the "default"?